# Ajuda com retorno de função!

Tags: php

Tenho a função abaixo que me adiciona um índice no segundo nível do array.
Está funcionando corretamente com o laço for.

```
<?php
function comparaArray($array1, $array2) { 

   for ($i = 0; $i < count($array2); $i++) {
     for ($j = 0; $j < count($array1); $j++) {


        if( $array2[$i][0] == $array1[$j][0] ) {
           $array2[$i][2] = "s";
           break;
        }   

    }   

    if(!isset($array2[$i][2])) {
        $array2[$i][2] = "n";
    }

 }

 return $array2;

}
?>
```

Fui tentar fazer a mesma coisa com o laço foreach e não funcionou!

```
<?php
function comparaArray1($array1, $array2) { 

   foreach ($array2 as $indice2) {

    foreach ($array1 as $indice1) {

       print $indice2[0]." == ".$indice1[0]."<br>";

       if($indice2[0] == $indice1[0]) {
            $indice2[2] = "s";
         break;
       }

    }

    if(!isset($indice2[2])) {
        $indice2[2] = "n";
    }

    echo "<br>";

   }

   print "<pre>";
   print_r($array2);
   print "</pre>";

   return $array2;


 }

?>
```

Algum recurso?

Array1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-02'
            [1] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-04'
            [1] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-09'
            [1] => 8
        )

)
```

Array2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-02'
            [1] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-03'
            [1] => 8
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-04'
            [1] => 8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-05'
            [1] => 8
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-06'
            [1] => 8
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-07'
            [1] => 8
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-08'
            [1] => 8
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => '2015-09'
            [1] => 8
        )

)
```

Comment: Parece que em nenhuma parte do código voce executa funções para inserir valores no array.

Comment: vou alterar a pergunta!

Comment: No seu array ele é bidimensional? Pq se não $i e $j ficaria na segunda casa $array[0][$i]. Tente da um var dump no seu array e veja como ta sendo os indices se ta 0,0 0,1 0,2 ou 0,0 0,1 0,2 depois 1,0

Comment: sim, são os mesmos! Eu apaguei né? Veja  pergunta de novo. Vou adicioná eles novamente!

Comment: Se ele é bidimensional as duas casas andam ex 0,0 0,1 depois 1,0 1,1 depois 2,0 2,1 pelo que vi no seu código o for só percorre as colunas tipo 0,0 depois 1,0 depois 2,0 quando fico confuso qnd é array bidimensional eu desenho ele no papel apenas os índices pra me ajuda tente fazer tbm possa ser que te ajude na primeira linha 0,0 0,1 0,2 na segunda linha 1,0 1,1 1,2 e assim por diante

Comment: Na primeira função esta inserindo os índices corretamente. Na segunda, no laço foreach, é que não esta. Mandei imprimir as saídas para ver.

Comment: vc precisa de qual dado do array a 'data' o 'numero' ou so dois.

Comment: no seu array1 tem 0,0 e 0,1 / 1,0 e 1,1 / 2,0 e  2,1 acho que seu codigo precisa de mais for, pq um array bidimensional precisa de dois for só pra percorrer ele

Comment: O Arrays tem a data e o número. Preciso comparar asa datas. Se encontrar alguma equivalência do array1 no array2, então cria o indice array1[][2] que não existe e dá valor 's' de encontrou. Caso contrário, cria o índice e dá valor 'n' que não encontrou. Mas não esta criando o índice!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui!

```
<?php
function comparaArray($array1, $array2) { 

   foreach ($array2 as $indice2=>$valor2) {

    foreach ($array1 as $indice1=>$valor1) {

       if($valor2[0] == $valor1[0]) {
            $array2[$indice2][2] = "s";
         break;
       }

    }

    if(!isset($array2[$indice2][2])) {
            $array2[$indice2][2] = "n";
    }

   }

   return $array2;   

 }

?>
```

Obrigado a todos!